# How can I send a string of text into another application?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, text, sendkeys

I'm playing a game called Tibia where you can cast "spells" and I want to make a program that says a string of text, every 60 seconds or so. Just to try it out.
This is in C# winforms.

I've tried using

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
SendKeys.Send(text);
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

But then I have to focus on the application (Tibia). I want to be able to send the keys to the application, even when it's running in the background. Could someone perhaps come up with a piece of code that would work for this?

And to be clear, I do not want to focus on the client. I have tried that, and it works good, but it's not what I want. I want to send a string of text completely in the background.

Comment: Seems that SendKeys is not what you are after. I quote: Use SendKeys to send keystrokes and keystroke combinations to the active application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Windows Automation seems like a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there no easier way to do this? I've never used an API before and I don't understand any of that. I'm a complete beginner. Isn't there anything like SendKeysToApplication.Send("hello world", applicationName); for example...

Comment: I read some website about SendMessage() but I can't find any code examples of it. Anyone here knows how to use SendMessage() to send a string, like "hello world" in to any application, let's say "Tibia.exe"?

Comment: http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson05.htm

Comment: Also, SendMessage requires you to use the Win32 API. ;)

Comment: Found something that worked and it's PostMessage() and it does exactly what I want, it does not focus on the window. But it seems I can only send one key at a time. Like the F1 key or a single letter like "A". But how the hell do I send a full string?

Comment: How about `foreach(char c in text) { PostMessage(...); }`?

Comment: This is the code to send F1 to the window. `PostMessage(Tibia_Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1, WM_KEYUP);` where I put `const int VK_F1 = 0x70;` at the top

Comment: autohotkey is probably more along the lines of what you need if you just want to make a quick bot for a game.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by sending Ctrl+V (paste). But first I set my string to the clipboard.